# Using Mercurial with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mercurial, codeplex

I am currently using Mercurial via Tortoise Hg for some of my side projects. I was wondering if there is tighter integration of Mercurial with Visual Studio 2010 via a plugin or some similar mechanism. What I'm thinking about is very similar to the git extensions which provide a plugin for VS. The plan is to eventually host the projects on Codeplex which supports Mercurial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's now mostly of historical interest.

Comment: Does "historical interest" = off-topic ???

Comment: I guess not. But the form of the question is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

sure there is [visualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) which works for 2005 to 2013 including 2010 .

another alternative (useful if you are in an environment where you don't have control over what is installed) is to use VS's external tools menus/buttons to launch tortoiseHg windows via thg

Answer (score 5):

I've been using [hgscc](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html) recently, and it works pretty well. It has a similar interface to TortoiseHG and also integrates with solution explorer. I've only used it with VS2008 but the website says it works with 2010 as well.

Comment: This is the one I'm using at the moment, and it does work with VS2010. I do like VisualHG a bit better at this time though.

Answer (score 3):

[VisualHg](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) + [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html). Also suggest to assign some hotkeys in VS2010 to call VisualHg functions like: File.Commit, File.RepoBrowser.

Answer (score 1):

See [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38689343/1233379).

The alternatives out there (for VS2010 through VS2015) are basically two: `VisualHG`, which is basically a GUI proxy for *TortoiseHg*, and `HgSccPackage`, which is a *stand-alone* package (*TortoiseHg* is not required).

Both of them can be installed free of charge through the Visual Studio's **Extensions and Updates...** GUI tool, accessible through the **Tools** menu.

To keep it short, the former gives a more wide set of options, while the latter doesn't require other software installed so it's (arguably) a more *lightweight* solution - and also easier to install and set-up. Choosing the right tool is up to you, I personally love the *TortoiseHg* interface and approach so VisualHG has always be my favourite choice.

For a more extensive comparison between them you can also read [this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/using-mercurial-hg-visual-studio-2015-visualhg-hgsccpackage/) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using shell-based mercurial commands + powerconsole add-in.